# How to convert from a decimal to hex in python without using hex()?

Tags: python, hex

I am new here, so please excuse any mistakes I may have made:)

I have been trying to send hex numbers over a virtual serial port pair using Python3 before I can test it on an actual device. However, the only ways to work with hex numbers I have found so far are:

a) Use them as a regular string

```
num_hex = input()
```

But this does not allow me to work on the numbers, as num_hex is a string

.

b) Convert them using int(,16)

```
ip_hex = input()
num_ip_hex = int(ip_hex, 16)
print(ip_hex, num_ip_hex, hex(num_ip_hex))
```

When used here num_ip_hex just store numbers in the form of base 10. For example the output for the print statement with input 'a' is

```
input[]: a
output[]: a 10 0xa
```

.

c) Use hex() and then use them

```
ip = input(">> ")
ip=int(ip, 16)
ip=hex(ip)
```

Again, this also gives a string.

I need a way to receive hex numbers and to be able to work with them further in that exact same way, not as strings or decimals. Is this possible?

EDIT: In short some form of hex that i can work with to like add, subtract, shift left etc.

Comment: What is a "hex number"? On most modern architectures, primitive number types are *binary*, and only the way they are printed to the screen is changed when you work with "hex numbers". Or perhaps you want a particular sequence of bytes, represented by the hexadecimal digits you are inputting?

Comment: Yes something like that. What I ultimately want to do is send a series of hexadecimal digits over a serial port to a machine, and to receive the incoming hexadecimal digits, so that i can check the encryption on them. For eg. if i receive "01 41 23 44 2f 5a", i later want to process them in a series of steps to check if the data sent is correct or tampered with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is storing data as bytes. Bytes actually have a built in method in python `.hex()` so you can always see a hex representation of it.

```
my_bytes = b'some words'
my_bytes.hex()   #'736f6d6520776f726473'
```

If you are sending the data raw as bytes, you could then do a direct comparison without worrying about hex at all. However, if you want to still send the hex as a string, you will need `binascii.unhexlify()`

```
import binascii
binascii.unhexlify('736f6d6520776f726473')    # b'some words'
```

Though it is generally preferred to send bytes, as then you do not have to worry about encoding and other issues.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Wanted to add dealing directly with the code you provided, it would look something like:

```
 comparable_bytes = b'verify_me'
 comparable_hex = '7665726966795f6d65'

 ip_hex = binascii.unhexlify(input('>> '))  # Input the Hex numbers

 assert ip_hex == comparable_bytes
 assert ip_hex.hex() == comparable_hex
```

Edit 2: Multiple hex character input

```
# Remove whitespace, allow for entry with or without spaces
ip = input().strip().replace(' ', '') 

bytestring  = binascii.unhexlify(ip)
```

Then you can directly send `bytestring`.

Comment: Thank you! But how do i convert hex to bytes to send it? This is all i figured out so far "ip = input()
    ip = int(ip,16)
    bytestring = ip.to_bytes(1, 'little')
    print("The number in integer is {int} in bytes is {bytes}".format(int=ip, bytes=bytestring), "and in hex is", hex(ip))"

Comment: Actually, that `bytestring` right there is it in bytes an can send that as is. Also going to edit post to show how to input multiple hex numbers at a time :)

Comment: okay so I tried using bytestring then, but when i reconvert it at the receiving end using "ip_int = int.from_bytes(ip, byteorder='little')", it gives me back a plain old decimal number. For example, I tried with "12", converted it to bytes, sent it, and then received it, what i get back after using the statement i mentioned here is "18", not "12". Could you please help me? :)

Comment: On the receiving end, try doing just do ip.hex(), instead of from_bytes

Comment: just tried it, it works, but it gives me 12 in the form of a string. I am so sorry to bother you again but is there a way to receive it as numerical 12?

Comment: I'm headed to bed shortly, but feel free to drop any more questions you have and I will try to answer all as best I can. If the answer did help you, I would appreciate it if you could accept it :)

Comment: It did help me with the input and conversion to bytes,, which i needed too so thank you so much, but my main issue is converting it to a form that can be numerically manipulated, like say "F+2=11". Is it possible to your knowledge? Because if it isn't then ill accept your answer right away

Comment: oh hey missed your comment when I was typing out mine, sry. What you were doing was correct then, as 12 in hex is 18 as an integer. In python you can store things as bytes, strings, ints or floats basically, there is not a direct Hex number to save, hence why I think bytes is best for you, as it's easy to convert between all bytes and view it as hex by doing .hex()

Comment: for example, 0F is valid hex but is not a valid number, so would have to be converted to 15 to be stored as an int, otherwise it needs to be stored as a string

Comment: you can also get the integer value of bytes by specifying their index, so ip[0] would return 18 when ip = b'12'

Comment: oh, just saw the F+2 comment. Ok, what you probably want then is to convert each position of the string to an integer, not the entire string directly to hex (will provide example)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was what i was looking for :)

Comment: let's use example 12 again, and now store as two separate ints, 16 (1×16 for first position) and 2. that way you could have an array or string of integer representations of hex numbers. I will try to write out a good example in morning but literally on phone in bed now lol, good luck til then!